# Managing images for a custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

My custom post type is for describing companies. Each post will require 4 images of specific type and size:

- Logo: 100 x 100
- Banner: 300 x 150
- Action image 1: 600 x 400
- Action image 2: 600 x 400

I'd like to simply store the files in a directory structure like this underneath wp-content somewhere and bypass or improve on the media upload dialog:

```
/orgs
   /good-deeds-inc
      /logo.jpg
      /banner.jpg
      /action1.jpg
      /action2.jpg
   /stout-heart
      /logo.jpg
      /banner.jpg
      /action1.jpg
      /action2.jpg
```

In creating the display and edit template, the attachment relationship would be assumed. I'd write a function that looks for the images in the expected place (plug of the custom post title). If not found a placeholder would be selected.

I like the simplicity for the person charged with gathering images. Simply put them in the proper directory.

My question is whether this simplification might lead to problems down the road. Perhaps there is a plug in that allows easier upload and management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin that assigns one image to a custom post type: [custom post type image](http://shop.social-ink.net/products/custom-post-type-images-wordpress-plugin).

Comment: Thanks. It looks useful, but I think my needs extend beyond that to managing several images for each custom post within my type.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the ability to add/edit images via WordPress admin for these custom post types? Or would they simply transfer the files over manually (FTP, SSH etc...) ?

Either way you could use the admin with this - but I am not sure you can use WordPress directly to handle the uploads, you would have to write a custom function.

It would make more sense to make use of the media manager and assign images to the  post or have custom meta fields where you can select an image etc... the location should not matter as you would check the value of the meta field not the physical location of an image (which is not a great idea if someone names a file incorrectly etc...)